# Pubnub iOS SDK Error - "pnmessagedeletecompletionblock not found"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, pubnub

Using Pubnub for my app.
**Issue in XCode 9**.

I am updating using cocoa pods (as mentioned in documentation)

> pod "PubNub", "~> 4"

Getting the following error:

> PNMessageDeleteCompletionBlock not found

[image]

Was not facing this issue before.
Need help which step can go wrong.

Comment: Have you imported the proper classes in this file?

Comment: Also, I would assum that your pod setting would get the latest version but trying running `gem update cocoapods` again and rebuild your project. Delete message feature was added in v4.7.0.

Comment: This file is a part of SDK itself, name of the file -  PNDeleteMessageAPICallBuilder.m

Comment: @CraigConover can you get it checked. This thing is troubling since I am not able to upload other files using cocoa pods.

Comment: Can you contact [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) with this issue? We can post back any useful details as an answer.